# Display Notes of Custom Stereotypes in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to create my own custom toolbox. Therefore I created a metaclass and a stereotype. In the stereotype I wrote a note that gives some instructions about how to populate the object.
Problem is, when I create my MDG Technology, the Notes won't display in the objects I create in my diagram..
How can I fix this and display the Notes for every object I create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either

- Write and MDG-Addin to populate the notes for your elements.
- Add an element with your stereotype to the template package and add the required notes there. This will have to be done on each model that uses your MDG.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Geert! Unfortunately my programming skills don't allow me to write my own add-in...
Any other possibility to pre-populate notes in elements? My toolbox should be used by multiple persons and so I'd like to tell them what they have to fill in where in order to create a correct RTF

Comment: Those two options are the only ones I can think of.

Comment: You do not have per chance such an add-in that allows for populating notes at hand?

Comment: No sorry. I do write add-ins for a living though. Contact me directly if interested: geert@bellekens.com

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'm assuming that you can see the notes you seek on the Properties page of an element you create using your toolbox i.e. the notes field is populated.

If it is, check that notes visibility is turned on by doing these two things:

1) Select the element and go to Element->Feature and Compartment Visibility. Check the Show Notes box. Hit OK

2) Right click on an element and choose Advanced->Use Rectangle Notation